# Alternative to define PhraseList in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, speech-recognition, windows-phone-8.1, speech-synthesis

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 App that makes use of the Speech API (Cortana to launch app). I have currently defined a phrase list, for example, like this,

```
    <CommandSet xml:lang="en-US" Name="myLaunchCommand">
    <CommandPrefix>Show Weather</CommandPrefix>
    <Example> Show Weather for Your City</Example>

    <Command Name="StartApp">
      <Example> For New York</Example>
      <ListenFor> For {city} [City]</ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Showing Weather for {city} </Feedback>
      <Navigate Target="MainPage.xaml" />
    </Command>

    <PhraseList Label="city">
      <Item>New Delhi</Item>
      <Item>Delhi</Item>
      <Item>Mumbai</Item>
      <Item>Chennnai</Item>
      <Item>Bangalore</Item>
      <Item>Moradabad</Item>
      <Item>New York</Item>
    </PhraseList>
  </CommandSet>
```

Now, I can have an unlimited number of phrases in the PhraseList "city". It is really not feasible to define all the cities in the world in the PhraseList. Is there any way to get that from the users' speech without defining a predefined list? How to deal with situations where we don't have the phrases ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a repository during runtime in code. Retrieve the countries from an api and update the phraselist...

For example, add this in your viewmodel

```
    public async Task UpdatePhraseList()
    {
        try
        {
            VoiceCommandDefinition commandDefinitions;

            string countryCode = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToLower();
            if (countryCode.Length == 0)
            {
                countryCode = "en-us";
            }

            if (VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstalledCommandDefinitions.TryGetValue("VoiceCommandSet_" + countryCode, out commandDefinitions))
            {
                List<string> YourNewData = new List<string>();


                await commandDefinitions.SetPhraseListAsync("yourkeyword", YourNewData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Updating Phrase list for VCDs: " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

}

And this is how you could call it from the app composite root:

```
// Update phrase list.
            ViewModel.ViewModelLocator locator = App.Current.Resources["ViewModelLocator"] as ViewModel.ViewModelLocator;
            if (locator != null)
            {
                await locator.YourViewModel.UpdatePhraseList();
            }
```

Comment: Its still not exact what you expect, but it atleast gives you a way to build it up from a resource